# Remove the "View" Link in Post Admin

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I have a custom post type that I'm just using just to keep data in but I sometimes share it with others, and I don't want any confusion when the "view" link appears in the admin column.

Is there a way of removing that?

[http://img.skitch.com/20110421-des28mtj4br3aeyfxnypnkghsy.jpg http://img.skitch.com/20110421-des28mtj4br3aeyfxnypnkghsy.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20110421-des28mtj4br3aeyfxnypnkghsy.jpg)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );

function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    if( get_post_type() === 'my_cpt' )
        unset( $actions['view'] );
    return $actions;
}
```

Should see you through :)

The $actions array consists of the following:

```
$actions['edit'] 
$actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] 
$actions['trash'] 
$actions['view']
```

To modify users grid view '`user_row_actions`' filter can be used.

For future reference.

Comment: Thanks Wild Phoenix, though it doesn't seem to be working. I add my cpt and the view link still appears.

Comment: Sorry I missed the braces on the method get_post_type() try that!

Comment: That did the trick! Awesome help Wild Phoenix. Much appreciated!

Comment: Where do I add the code above?

Comment: @Darren You can simply copy paste this code into your functions.php file of your template. Hope that helps!

Comment: I need to remove view link in uers.php in wordpress. I used add_filter( 'user_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 ); and it is working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to remove the "View" link under the users in the backend User panel? All users are listed with an Edit, Delete, View link. I'm looking to remove that View link. Much appreciated.