# Remove Post Page "View Post" Link

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, columns

I have created a custom post type, but it just to list some data on a page and it doesn't have any single.php.

How do i disable so on the post page when i click publish it doesn't show the "View Page" link and also how do i disable the "View" link in the columns for that post type.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Changing the `public` argument of `register_post_type()` will remove the link to view your custom post type publicly.

```
'public' => false,
```

See: [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)

Note that this will also hide your custom post type from the admin navigation menus, which you might not want. To hide the 'View Post' link but keep your post type in the admin menus use `show_ui` as well like so:

```
'public'  => false,
'show_ui' => true,
```

Comment: "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please add some explanation to your answer and links to relevant sources, such as the Codex.

Comment: I test this on my site before posting answer here.

Comment: Aki check this. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/remove-the-view-link-in-post-admin
I notice that this is the similar question (solved).

Comment: If you are response about testing the answer is directed at me, I said nothing about whether the answer is correct or not, just that you need to add some explanation to it.

Comment: This works in 2019.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is incorrect. The message at the top of a post edit page cannot be modified using labels. You need to use the `post_updated_messages` filter.

The following function will customize the messages using the name of the post type - handy if you're using custom post types. It's a modified version of the example on the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example).

Notice that the View and Preview links are controlled with the `$viewLink`, `$previewLink`, and `$schedPreviewLink` variables, which will only appear if the visibility of the current post's post type is set to public.

```
function custom_post_type_messages($messages) {
  global $post, $post_ID;

  $post_type = get_post_type( $post_ID );
  $obj = get_post_type_object($post_type);

  $singular = $obj->labels->singular_name;

  $viewLink = ($obj->public) ?  ' <a href="%s">View '.strtolower($singular).'</a>' : "";
  $previewLink = ($obj->public) ? ' <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview '.strtolower($singular).'</a>': "";
  $schedPreviewLink = ($obj->public) ? ' <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview '.strtolower($singular).'</a>': "";

  $messages[$post_type] = array(
    0 => '', // Unused. Messages start at index 1.
    1 => sprintf( __($singular.' updated.'.$viewLink), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
    3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
    4 => __($singular.' updated.'),
    5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __($singular.' restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
    6 => sprintf( __($singular.' published.'.$viewLink), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    7 => __('Page saved.'),
    8 => sprintf( __($singular.' submitted.'.$previewLink), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
    9 => sprintf( __($singular.' scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>.'.$schedPreviewLink), date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    10 => sprintf( __($singular.' draft updated.'.$previewLink), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
  );
  return $messages;
}

add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'custom_post_type_messages' );
```

Comment: While woefully lacking in detail, the [previous answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/119126/21376) by @pendjer is not wrong. Setting the `public` _argument_ to `false` does remove the "View" links on both the edit "index" table and the main edit screen. And that seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @s_ha_dum 'when i click publish it doesn't show the "View Page"' indicates to me the message that is displayed at the top of the page when a post is published or updated. Simply changing the public argument to false will not remove this message/link. It still appears, and the link will produce a 404 error.

Comment: Yes, View Post link still appears after publishing post in backend, gonna try this method now.