# Remove the “View” Link in Post edit Admin

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );

function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    if( get_post_type() == 'my_cpt' )
        unset( $actions['view'] );
    return $actions;
}
```

This code removes the view link from post list, but I want to remove the link from post edit page also. Can anyone help ?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/remove-the-view-link-in-post-admin same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The Edit Permalink HTML including the View-Post button is passed through the `get_sample_permalink_html` filter. You will likely have to `preg_replace()` the view post button out of it:

```
function my_get_sample_permalink_html($a){
    return preg_replace("/<span id='view-post-btn'>(.*)<\/span>/",'',$a);
}
add_filter('get_sample_permalink_html','my_get_sample_permalink_html');
```

(2) The message after a post has been updated can be altered by filtering `post_updated_messages`. Like this:

```
function my_post_updated_messages( $messages ) {
    $messages['post'][1] = __('Post updated');
    return $messages;
}
add_filter('post_updated_messages','my_post_updated_messages');
```

Comment: This is great, but there are other messages that feature a link to the post,
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b1474a8a209eafdcca1f14a868ff963587f0156b/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L180

And there is a link also in the admin bar.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure post args public and publicly_queryable are set to false.
or use

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 2 );

function remove_row_actions( $actions, $post )
{
    if ($post->post_type == "post_type") {
        unset( $actions['view'] );
    }
    return $actions;
}
```